# jQuery fill the prepared HTML div dynamically with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**What i have:**

1. JSON with id, name, position, department and address.
2. That same JSON have over 1000 random employees looped to a table.
3. Every person have a custom attribute (user_id) and same css class for hovering.
4. One hidden prepared and styled div for information when is hovered on one employee.

**What i need:**

1. I need when i hover on some employee to display all that employee information like name, position, department and address. Keep in mind that hover is working, but informations are still static. So basically, my logic is when custom attr user_id and JSON id match = fill the html.
   How can i do that?

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-eu.hipchat.com/189576/1743369/lDhMee0RoA1IO5D/generated.json";
var employees;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        employees = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        write(employees);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();


function write(arr) {
    var i;
    var out = '<table>';
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<tr>';
        out += '<td class="hoverKartX" user_id="' + arr[i].id + '">' + arr[i].name + '</td>';
        out += '<td>' + arr[i].position + '</td>';
        out += '</tr>';
    }
    out += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('employees').innerHTML = out;
}

$(function() {
  var moveLeft = 20;
  var moveDown = 10;

  $('.hoverKartX').hover(function(e) {
    //$(this).parent().find(".hoverKart").show();

    $(".hoverKart").show();
  }, function() {
    $('.hoverKart').hide();
  });

  $('.hoverKartX').mousemove(function(e) {
    $(".hoverKart").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);

    // preventing 'falling' to the right on smaller screen
    if ($(".hoverKart").position()['left'] + $('.hoverKart').width() > $(window).width()) {
        $(".hoverKart").css("left", $(window).width() - $(".hoverKart").width());
    };

    // preventing 'falling from the bottom of the page'
    if ((e.pageY + moveDown + $(".hoverKart").height()) > ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())) {
      $(".hoverKart").css("top", $(window).height() - $(".hoverKart").height() + $(window).scrollTop());
    }
});


});
```

```css
.hoverKart {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 220px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- hidden div-->
<div class="hoverKart">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cardTop"><p><!-- JSON DATA (ID) --></p></div>
            <div class="imgHolder">
                <img class="employee" src="img/img.jpg" alt="employee image">
                <img class="eLogo" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
            </div>
            <div class="eInformation">
                <p class="eName"><!-- JSON DATA (NAME) --></p>
                <p class="ePos"><!-- JSON DATA (DEPARTMENT) --></p>
            <div class="eDep">
                <img src="img/icons-dep/5.png" alt="department logo">
            </div>
            <p class="eOp">Operations</p>
            <p class="eOp2"><!-- JSON DATA (ADDRESS) --></p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="employees"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can check my answer. I have a created working fiddle of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have update your code and created a fiddle:

Check the [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/n47zrand/42/).

```
$(function(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var myGlobalJson;
var url = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-eu.hipchat.com/189576/1743369/lDhMee0RoA1IO5D/generated.json";
var employees;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        employees = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        myGlobalJson = employees;
        write(employees);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();




function write(arr) {
    var i;
    var out = '<table>';
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<tr>';
        out += '<td class="hoverKartX" user_id="' + arr[i].id + '">' + arr[i].name + '</td>';
        out += '<td>' + arr[i].position + '</td>';
        out += '</tr>';
    }
    out += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('employees').innerHTML = out;
    bindMethods();
}

//$(function() {
function bindMethods(){
  var moveLeft = 20;
  var moveDown = 10;

  $('.hoverKartX').hover(function(e) {
    //$(this).parent().find(".hoverKart").show();
        var currentUserId = parseInt(($(this).attr('user_id')));
    //console.log(myGlobalJson);
    //console.log(typeof  parseInt($(this).attr('user_id')));
    $.each(myGlobalJson, function(i, item) {
      //console.log($(this).attr('user_id'));
    if(item.id === currentUserId){
      $(".hoverKart .cardTop").html(item.id);
      $(".hoverKart .eName").html(item.name);
      $(".hoverKart .ePos").html(item.position);
      $(".hoverKart .eOp2").html(item.address);  
      return false;
    }
});

    $(".hoverKart").show();
  }, function() {
    $('.hoverKart').hide();
  });

  $('.hoverKartX').mousemove(function(e) {
    $(".hoverKart").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);

    // preventing 'falling' to the right on smaller screen
    if ($(".hoverKart").position()['left'] + $('.hoverKart').width() > $(window).width()) {
        $(".hoverKart").css("left", $(window).width() - $(".hoverKart").width());
    };

    // preventing 'falling from the bottom of the page'
    if ((e.pageY + moveDown + $(".hoverKart").height()) > ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())) {
      $(".hoverKart").css("top", $(window).height() - $(".hoverKart").height() + $(window).scrollTop());
    }
});
}
//});
});
```

There were some issues in existing code:

1. You should bind `hover` method to field only when your `write` method execution is finished. Otherwise, it's working will be inconsistent, depending on how fast `table` is created.

I hope, It will solve your purpose.

Comment: @Bojan Glad, I could help. You can mark the answer as done for others' reference.

Comment: @Bojan I had a question?

Answer (score 1):

Alright apology for different answer as it's whole different way to fix this issue like below,

As your main problem is your "hoverKartX" jquery events are not binded to  any elements because your html elements are generated dynamically from xmlhttp, so first you need to make sure your events are binded to your html elements after generating it, probably you need to refactor your code and move your $('.hoverKartX').hover()... and $('.hoverKartX').mousemove()... in your function write(arr) as you had attached your mousehover and mousemove event's code in global context which will bind to no html element at the time of page load because you are generating these elements dynamically using xmlhttp,

then access your custom html attribute user_id by using jquery's attr like $(this).attr('user_id') in your mousehover or mousemove event and do whatever you want to do...

Comment: I understand this, but i need only in way i described before.

Comment: I need to match both id's, and after that fill the html.

Comment: you have only one id which you are getting from element on which mousehover event fired ? so you need to show that user_id's information by  doing $('#some_user_id').show(); ?

Comment: I have one custom attribute (user_id) which is filled from JSON "id".
On that td elements i have same class which triggers .hoverKart on hover.
Now when user_id matches with JSON id i need to show more information from JSON on that particular person.